# Split given integer into a given number of integers, each within given bounds

Tags: code-golf, random, integer-partitions

## Input variables:

(Names are just examples, they don't need to be named like this)

- `GrandTotal` - integer to divide
- `SplitCount` - number of output integers required
- `UpperLimit` - highest valid value for any one output integer
- `LowerLimit` - lowest valid value for any one output integer

## Valid Output:

Outout must be a random set of `SplitCount` integers, each between `UpperLimit` and `LowerLimit` (your language's RNG is fine), the sum of which is `GrandTotal`.

The output should be uniformly random in that any valid output should be equally likely. For example input of [8,3,4,2]  has the following six valid outputs:

1. 2,3,3
2. 3,2,3
3. 3,3,2
4. 2,2,4
5. 2,4,2
6. 4,2,2

Each output should have, therefore, 1/6 chance of occurring.

The order of the output matters: 5,8,7 is not an equal set to 5,7,8. Both outputs must be equally likely if either is possible. 
<sub>(This does mean that output where all three integers are the same is less likely output to one where all three are different: Given `GrandTotal`=6, `SplitCount`=3, `UpperLimit`=4, `LowerLimit`=1, a set including 1, 2 and 3 can appear in 6 different configurations, while a set of all 2s can only appear in one, making it 6 times as likely that *one of* the varied sets will appear, rather than the set of 3 2s.)</sub>

## Valid Input:

Any input variables should work, assuming that the following is true

1. `UpperLimit` * `SplitCount` >= `GrandTotal`
2. `LowerLimit` * `SplitCount` <= `GrandTotal`
3. all input variables are positive integers.

### Tie-Breaker

Submissions that accept invalid input but return output as though it was the closest valid input would win a tie-breaker. (eg `GrandTotal`=10, `SplitCount`=2, `UpperLimit`=3, `LowerLimit`=2 returning [5,5] treats the `UpperLimit` variable as though it was the lowest valid input, rather than what it was.) Closest here means change as few variables as possible, and change those variables by the smallest possible integer. Ideally, change the latest possible variable(s) (here, `SplitCount` could have been changed to make input valid, but `UpperLimit` is a later variable.)

## Sample in-out range

| GrandTotal | SplitCount | UpperLimit | LowerLimit | Possible Output Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 | 7 | 4 | 4,7;5,6;6,5;7,4 |
| 8 | 3 | 11 | 2 | 2,3,3;3,2,3;3,3,2;2,2,4;2,4,2;4,2,2 |
| 13 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 8,5;7,6;6,7;5,8 |
| 16 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 8,8 |
| 16 | 2 | 10 | 4 | 10,6;9,7;8,8;7,9;6,10 |
| 16 | 4 | 10 | 4 | 4,4,4,4 |

Comment: I don’t understand the worked example… splitCount is 4 but all outputs have 3 items. “Must be a random set of splitcount integers”. Also they sum to 8, not 10.

Comment: @Jonah Weird, I thought I'd updated that to be correct. Oh well, thanks for the catch, fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŸIãʒOQ}Ω
```

Inputs in the order `UpperLimit,LowerLimit,SplitCount,GrandTotal`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6A7Pw4tPTfIPrD238v9/cy4TLiMuQ0MA) or [verify all test cases (without the `}Ω`)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCaFjx/6M7Ig8vPjXJPyLwf63O/@hocx0THSMdQ8NYnWhDQyDLWMcCyLSAiBojmGYgBQZobBMQOxYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ÿ       # Take the first two (implicit) inputs and push a list in the range
        # [LowerLimit,UpperLimit]
 Iã     # Create all combinations of a size of the third input SplitCount using
        # the cartesian product
   ʒ    # Filter this list of lists by:
    O   #  Sum the list
     Q  #  Check if it's equal to the fourth (implicit) input GrandTotal
   }Ω   # After the filter: pop and leave a random list
        # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

```
RandomChoice@Pick[t=Range@##3~Tuples~#2,Tr/@t,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcgxDoIwGEDhnWs0YfqNLSXKgmnCBYiykQ61FmmEYqBMhF69FnRz@97rhW1VL6yWwje5vwrzGPqiHbRUrNTyVds8vKdiCFFXze9OTQ4lUI1HZgHx2JejNrZGh0sxzMZOrBL3TtUNYwgIxpjz2N2kMG6JFoIhhQTSFYLJJjhvzoCGIGT/dP/Z7tOfCf5F@o1o9R8)

Input `[GrandTotal, SplitCount, LowerLimit, UpperLimit]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 116 bytes

*-12 bytes thanks to `Jitse`*

Accepts input in the form of `GrandTotal,SplitCount,UpperLimit,LowerLimit`.
Returns a randomly picked range, as a tuple, from a list of possible ranges.

```python
lambda g,s,u,l:r.choice([p for p in i.product(range(l,u+1),repeat=s)if sum(p)==g])
import random as r,itertools as i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BboMwEATQe75ijra6iuISJQiJL6EcHDDEksGrtX3o15MQNWoPPb6d0Q5/53tcq5plm9qvLdjlNlrMlKhQaOQ43KMfnOoYUxQw/Ap/ZIljGbISu85OBSofRpM4dja3SfsJqSyKddvOvT74haNkPLtjXGAThHx2kmMMaaff9s8zIREKIewTXWcM4ZNwJZx7QlcTKsLruNNUr7T@Sc3lP5rTH5/f7psDwOLXrCb1u6r19gA)

Comment: You're missing a random in there. I misread the challenge at first as well, but the idea is to output one of those possible lists at random. So you can keep your existing approach, and pick a random item from that list to output.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you for your feedback, I think it works properly now. If not let me know.

Comment: You need to output only one of the options at random. [This saves you 12 bytes.](https://tio.run/##bc3BboMwEATQe75ijra6iuISJQiJL6EcHDDEksGrtX3o15MQNWoPPb6d0Q5/53tcq5plm9qvLdjlNlrMlKhQaOQ43KMfnOoYUxQw/Ap/ZIljGbISu85OBSofRpM4dja3SfsJqSyKddvOvT74haNkPLtjXGAThHx2kmMMaaff9s8zIREKIewTXWcM4ZNwJZx7QlcTKsLruNNUr7T@Sc3lP5rTH5/f7psDwOLXrCb1u6r19gA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jitse Thank you for you clarification, I misread the part of the challenge about returning just one random choice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 49 bytes

```
r@s1Js2rzjCBf{++g2==}f{{g1j~[}al}sa-.3 0x/rn1.+si
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNCsIwEIXX6SmCGxedaCaJbSUooq68gIvaRYUqLUW0QRBLvXqdVBEZ5ve9@Y73pi7c7V709YWLjI/EcmStyPbbFrnkmqvOlWOeZof0WvTNyuHOqeZZbdanNgzParHoTm17xuqVdnnduVxMNJePaXPBSejKvkdkisXMcLFkBmI7g8hGMLMxmCBhmnndawo0aKtBDZW6VTQbqoZmSlABamIlH1YyMDzLM5MAo3/tu6P8HFCSc05OUuhrTl8ovcX8LAaGeAM)

```
r@s1          # Range from lowerLimit to upperLimit and save to 1
Js2           # Duplicate grandTotal and save to 2
rz            # Range [0, grandTotal]
jCB           # Combinations of SplitCount
f{++g2==}     # Filter for sum == grantTotal
f{{g1j~[}al}  # Filter for all elements in range
sa-.3 0x/rn   # Generate infinite list of random numbers [0, len)
1.+si         # Take 1 and select it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 164 bytes

```bash
echo>0
seq 1 $2|xargs -I, sh -c "rm ,;seq $4 $3|xargs -i sh -c \"<\$((,-1)) sed s/^/{}\ />>,\""
<$2 tr \  +|sed s/+$//|bc|pr -mt $2 -|grep $1$|cut -d\	 -f1|shuf -n1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc3BCoIwHAfgcz7Fj7GD4saaCR0S773DCHRO7WDZphC0nv1fUZ2/w9c2YSRydrzW2yS4GzR4Ee@NHwLkUSCMkBbMTxCHD/MSfPf3848NqwxPUyF1liG4DkGd1ONpoOpaGMaSihdYPAyQx6/nXKnY2jh7yGl5n5Bx8G4G1zzadYHszAay1zGMaw950USkNRW0p/IF)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 85 bytes

Expects `(count, lower, upper)(total)`.

```javascript
(n,a,b)=>g=(t,k=n,s=t,...o)=>k?g(t,k-1,s-=q=a-Math.random()*(~b+a)|0,...o,q):s?g(t):o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dTsIwFIDveYpjYkLrzppViBJm8cpL4wMsSyijwNhcYSsSMuer4ykzxAtu2n7f@ek5W/2lm6zOdy6s7NKcV@rMKtS44Gq2VsxhoSpslEMhhCVXvK69DCU2odorHb5rtxG1rpb2k/EH9rMINP@OLum459PG5/OpPcfJACCREh9xjPCcokeY4IiElD3KUR@d/OHTLZTRFcc9DtKBWNn6TWcbxhJnnS4RMnuoHEJpj6ZGOOx2pk45qBm0VFwaB43TDhS0XUyCypmXOZkopusFZBT5VxBwaC8FhTnFsLRErj7RSUzZK3bjJ84uU3CxtXnFhjjkMXSQaUcTGurXER03eWnYHXWhoB8moWdKHcOfK1EVDfex2JrMCRIN8yEuGls7xq9LF36vzFaNLY0o7ZpEAHNg923fKe34nHO/5/8kEh0//wI)

(NB: The function is likely to stack overflow on some test cases. The above test includes some extra recovery code.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 34 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ≔⊕⁻ＮζεＩ‽ΦＥＸεη⁺﹪÷ιＸε…⁰ηεζ⁼Σιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3JCoMwEIbveQqPE7Bgl5un0gU8WKR9gtQEDWTRLBZ8@XSkLUjnMMzHfPNP2zPXWqZSqswQwy3qp3Aw0pKsuf/jGfnovewMVKZ1QgsTBIdamuhhLdI8myk2gQeNkybAifkAd2a41XCVKqBUswEa@8JJ5FmPdqMwprY8Kotp4SwnyQVIXPwsDOgEFIv@if/@uYyRKQ@PqEEijnSpMqVtQfZkRw5pM6k3) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order GrandTotal, SplitCount, LowerLimit, UpperLimit. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input the grand total, split count and lower limit.

```
≔⊕⁻Ｎζε
```

Input the upper limit and calculate the length of the inclusive range from the lower limit to the upper limit.

```
Ｉ‽ΦＥＸεη⁺﹪÷ιＸε…⁰ηεζ⁼Σιθ
```

Generate the Cartesian product of the split count number of inclusive ranges, filter out those whose sum isn't the desired grand total, and output one uniformly at random.